# how to create space between columns using css flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to create space between columns that I build with css flex. I do not want to use padding or margin.

There could be between 2 or 6 columns.

If two columns they could have several width variations like

50% / 50%
25% / 75%
75% / 25%

etc

How can I introduce some space between columns that does not use padding or margin, since I want space just between columns and not space all around columns.

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: You could use `justify-content:space-between` i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this answer I want to show by not using `margin`, what you miss out on one of Flexbox's clever behavior, where when flex items doesn't fit (wider than their parent), they are able to shrink equally and keep each column's proportional width.

So to answer your question: *How can I introduce some space between columns that does not use padding or margin, since I want space just between columns and not space all around columns*

Answer: *You add the margin between each column, not on all sides*

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container .column {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.container .column:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 5px;                       /*  on all but the first column  */
}
.container .column:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 5px;                      /*  on all but the last column  */
}

.container .column:nth-child(1),
.container .column:nth-child(2) {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
.container .column:nth-child(3),
.container .column:nth-child(6) {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}
.container .column:nth-child(4),
.container .column:nth-child(5) {
  flex-basis: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: damn another great answer, not sure which answer to pick now, your solution is good since I do not have to calculate manually width of each column when user increases the spacing. I am building a visual page designer where user can enter spacing and that would mean using previously suggested solution I would have to perform calculations to be able to introduce spacing. Are there any negatives with using your approach or is just perfect solution for what I need?

Comment: @maxit You are the only one who can decide whether mine or the other is the perfect for you, and which to pick...and for sure, neither of us will feel bad if you pick the other, so go with what feels best for you :)

Comment: one more question, since I allow user to interactivly play with this and I am using vuejs I incject this as inline style. Is it possible to inject stuff like this .column:nth-child(1) as inline style? how would that be done? If not possible then I can't use it

Comment: @maxit No need for `nth-child` when using inline style, you add the width and margin's straight to each child based on if it is not the first/last

Comment: any experience with vuejs, now really sure how I would squize that check into this code, check the gist: https://gist.github.com/iwebnaut/a905eb285b468fbcd1e7a67eda7b0027 this is the line where I apply inline style: v-bind:style="{'width': column.width,'padding': columnPadding}" how to apply margin if first and last item, not sure how it would be done with vue

Comment: how about in my css I give first item 0 left margin and last item 0 right margin and then in my code I apply the margin user entered and all other columns will get it correctly?

Comment: @maxit Maybe like this: https://jsfiddle.net/f68vjf2b/

Comment: I got it working by specifing in css first and last child to have 0 left and right margin and then just applying margin: 0 Npx, N being whatever user entered

Comment: @maxit Also, somewhere I guess you have a CSS file that loads, so here is another option: https://jsfiddle.net/f68vjf2b/1/ .... and I see you figured this one out already :)

Comment: yeah I have, one last related question, if I have 5 columns and because I need my columns to be responsive and look good, I want to at specific browser width to make them all  100% width and taking 1 row each, would that cause any problems with your suggested solution?

Comment: @maxit Like this you mean: https://jsfiddle.net/f68vjf2b/2/ .... resize width and check

Comment: yeah thanks for perfect solution

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example with no padding or margin. I'm using `justify-content: space-between` on the parent flexbox div, and leaving 10% of width available for spacing by making the columns 20% and 70% (90% total) respectively.

```css
.flex {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.column {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 20%;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="column col-1">20%</div>
  <div class="column col-2">70%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: now that is a smart solution, thanks for posting this

Comment: and with responsive capabilities?

Comment: @stackdave Yes, it uses percentages so it's responsive. Are you asking about adding media queries?

Comment: not really, because it's small can see it mode responsive, i've got using; flex-wrap:wrap